# How to construct url suitable for django from html form action

Tags: html, django, forms, action

I have django site which I can query with various combinations of parameters. I am trying to write a html form for selecting the various combinations like so :

```
<form action="http://mydjangosite.com/summaryReports/" target="_blank">
  <input type="radio" name="reportType" value="messageSummary" checked> messageSummary<br>
  <input type="radio" name="reportType" value="countSummary"> countSummary<br>

  <select name="period">
    <option value="today">Today</option>
    <option value="yesterday">Yesterday</option>
    <option value="thisWeek">This Week</option>
    <option value="lastWeek">Last Week</option>
    <option value="thisMonth">This Month</option>
    <option value="lastMonth">Last Month</option>
  </select>
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="reportFormat" value="html" checked> html<br>
  <input type="radio" name="reportFormat" value="pdf"> pdf<br>
  <input type="radio" name="reportFormat" value="csv"> csv<br>
  <input type="radio" name="reportFormat" value="email"> email<br>
  <input type="radio" name="reportFormat" value="debug"> debug<br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

When I press button the url generated is :

```
mydjangosite.com/summaryReports/?reportType=messageSummary&period=today&reportFormat=html
```

whereas what I require is :

```
mydjangosite.com/summaryReports/messageSummary/today/html
```

How to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you'd need a view that would process the options selected, and an url that would react to the pattern, so, your view, which should be the one associated to `/summaryReports/` will do something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def rewrite_the_url(request):
    return redirect('your_app:actual_reports', **request.GET.dict())
```

now, the url definition here is important, as your view up there will pass all the parameters to it, so you'd want:

```
url(r'/summaryReports/(?P<reportType>[^./]+)/(?P<period>[^./]+)/(?P<reportFormat>[^./]+)/', views.actual_reports, name='actual_reports')
```

Then, `actual_reports` should be declared as:

```
def actual_reports(request, reportType, period, reportFormat):
    #return something
```

Remember that an URL represents an state of your application, it's not a decorative measure, an user can simply change the parameter of your URL and expect things to change, what we're doing here is rewriting an URL to change what we get as a query string to an URL, as Django or the UWSGI server of your choice don't have any concern over the rewriting, as you would expect with systems that user Apache + mod_rewrite, which is server tech, not an application framework.

Comment: _redirect_ is the key. Now I can figure out what to do. Thanks for the lead

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from sellerProfile import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^summaryReports'+'/(?P<reportType>[\w\-]+)'+'/(?P<period>[\w\-]+)'+'/(?P<reportFormat>[\w\-]+)/$', views.summaryReportHtml, name="summaryReports")
]
```

you have to create `urlpattern` in `urls.py` and in view.py file you have to get values like.

```
@csrf_exempt
@token_required
def summaryReports(request, reportType, period, reportFormat):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print(reportType, period, reportFormat)
```

Comment: I already have code similar to what you have given, in my views.py. My question was, how to convert the parameters in the  'GET' request to the URL chain as required by django

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

```
def reportGenerator(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        QryDict = request.GET
    else:
        QryDict = request.POST

    reportType = QryDict.get('reportType', 'rawRecords')
    period = QryDict.get('period', 'today')
    reportFormat = QryDict.get('reportFormat','html')

    newURL = '/summaryReports/' + reportType + '/' + period + '/' + reportFormat + '/'

    return redirect( newURL )
```

`